# Apply multiple discount codes to cart when landing page is reached

Tags: javascript, shopify

I am trying to apply 2 discount codes that are product-based:

1. Product A gets a flat 200 discount (CODE1)
2. Product B gets a flat 300 discount (CODE2)

Both discount codes are configured to work together (combination).

I want it so that when a user gets to a specific landing page, we automatically apply CODE1 and CODE2 to the cart preemptively via JS

I tried:

```
function applyDiscountCode(discountCode) {
    fetch(`/discount/${discountCode}`)
        .then(function () {
            console.log('applied discount: ' + discountCode);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.error('error applying discount: ', error);
        });
}

const discountCodes = [
    'CODE1',
    'CODE2'
];

discountCodes.forEach((code) => {
    applyDiscountCode(code);
});
```

But when I go to the landing page, and afterwards add both products to the cart only one of the products discount is showing up. I am unsure if this is a limitation of Shopify or if there is another methodology for doing this?